# How should I use Svelte Reactivity with DOM getElementById?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, svelte, svelte-component

I have a div element where it is scrollable

```
    <script>
        let scrollBoxObj;
        $: scrollBoxObj = document.getElementById("chat-box");
        
        $: if (!(scrollBoxObj === undefined) && scrollBoxObj.scrollTop < scrollBoxObj.scrollHeight) {
            scrollBoxObj.scrollTop = scrollBoxObj.scrollHeight;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="scrollBox" class="h-screen w-auto chat-box border border-orange rounded">
        <div id="chat-box" style="margin: 0" class="chat-box">
            {#each chatBox as { user, content, type}}
                <MessageBox {user} message={content} {type} />
            {/each}
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .chat-box {
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    </style>
```

i am trying to auto scroll down when a new message is added.
but it is not reactive.
or i didn't understand how reactivity works in svelte.
i also tried to assign scrollBoxObj in onMount but it was still the same result didn't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Svelte, the reactivity from `$: x = y` kicks in when there is a change on the left side from the equation (the `y`-part).

In your code you have

```js
$: scrollBoxObj = document.getElementById("chat-box");
```

On the left side we have a string (*"chat-box"*) which is a constant and will never change, there is also the *document* which will also never change, this means the reactivity will not work as you expect.

When working with Svelte using `document.getElementById` (or any of the other selector methods) is considered bad practice because you are interacting directly with the DOM, while your DOM should rather be a reflection of your state. In short: don't do it.

Svelte provides you with an easy way to bind a DOM-node (like a *div*) to a variable by simply adding `bind:this={variable}`

In your case this would become:

```html
<script>
 let scrollbox
</script>

<div bind:this={scrollbox}>
 ...
</div>
```

The *reactive declaration* (the *if* block) will execute whenever anything inside it changes, which is scrollbox in your case:

```js
$: if (scrollBoxObj && scrollBoxObj.scrollTop < scrollBoxObj.scrollHeight) {
  scrollBoxObj.scrollTop = scrollBoxObj.scrollHeight;
}
```

Just note here again that this will only trigger when *scrollbox* changes, once it is bound you will not retrigger (for instance when the user scrolls, it will not do anything) for that you should probably use an `on:scroll` event.